# In VS2013 SSIS, How do I set the value of a project parameter using a query?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssis

I'm a little new to SSIS through VS2013. I'd like to create a project parameter, and set the value using a SQL query.

Something like:

@MyProjectParameter = (Select TOP 1 CustomerID from CustomerTable)

Please let me know if anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the project parameter is? Why can't you use a variable and set it in the beginning or in a parent package?

Comment: Where are you looking to set this value? Obviously, you can't define that within the Parameter itself and a Parameter is read-only for the execution of the package. So, are you asking how do I set it from a Parent/Child package set up, or from an SSISDB execution, or SQL Agent or some other mechanism that isn't coming to mind?